# Switch Wordpress database outside Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have two Wordpress blogs on the same domain/server - one regular posts the other videos - plus other non-Wordpress pages which have a box with the latest blog posts using this code:

```
<ul>
<?php 
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php');
    $args = array(
        'cat' => 5, // Only source posts from a specific category
        'posts_per_page' => 1 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
    );
    $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
    if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <span class="post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <span class="post_thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
        </a>
        <span class="post_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
    </li>   
<? } 
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

All works as I want it. However we now want a second box under the first on the same pages with posts from the other blog (video). As wp-load.php has already been included for the first blog box it gets posts from the wrong blog.

How can I swap the database connection to the settings for the other (video) blog?

I have searched for solutions and found

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost );
```

I am lost as to how to use this and make it work.

I have considered merging them in to one blog but that seems a bit excessive for what would seem a simple problem so would rather not do that.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried wordpress multisite ?

Comment: I haven't. Was one of my thoughts but seems a bit overkill.